# java: add KM to given latitude and longitude

Tags: java, latitude-longitude

I have a given latitude and longitude say (LAT,LONG).

Now I want to add 30KM to this LAT,LONG and want to know result value of lat,long for all direction(north,south,NE,SE..) i.e what will be the lat long value for north,south,NE,SE direction after LAT+30KM,LONG+30KM

How can i implement this in java?

Comment: Answering this question will require a lot of assumptions at this point. Do you have a code sample ?

Comment: no idon't have any code sample just searching.What kind of assumption u are talking about

Comment: Data type primarily, but, if you don't have any code, it doesn't matter. The answer can just make those assumptions without worrying about having it fit your question.

Answer (score 3):

This is called calculating the lat/lon from a bearing and range.  See the section **Destination point given distance and bearing from start point** at this website:  http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

The range will be 30 km.  Your bearings will be 0 (north); π/2 (east); π (south) and 3/2 π (west).

Answer (score 1):

**Haversine formula** may help you here.You can refer [This](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) link.

Comment: I have implemented `Haversine formula` in java when i use same lat long in my app and google map. my app shows shows 1km less difference then google map